# Understanding font families, font styles and how to reference them in CSS

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am working with fonts, and I have recently discovered some mistakes I have been making. So I need to understand what I was exactly doing wrong.

### Adroid Roboto family

I have installed on my machine the [Roboto font family](https://material.io/guidelines/resources/roboto-noto-fonts.html), so now this is what I see in my system under `Fonts`:

[image]

But as you can see, I have a family installed, if I drill down inside it, I see this:

[image]

#### My web application

So, in my web application, I have a CSS style defining fonts:

```
.mytext {
  font-family "Roboto Regular", Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
.mytext-bold {
  font-family "Roboto Bold", Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
```

The problem is that the font, when I visualize the page, is not correct. When I visualize the page, I see `Tahoma`.

So, if I open one of the font styles, I see this:

[image]

So I realized that the name I have to use in `family-name` is `Roboto`, not `Roboto Regular` or `Roboto Bold` as shown in the style name in `Fonts` folder:

```
.mytext {
  font-family Roboto, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
.mytext-bold {
  font-family Roboto, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
```

### Questions

But then, how to apply the different styles? `myfont-bold` is supposed to have the bold style, but if the name is always `Roboto` to use in `font-family`, how can I get the different style tuning offered?

The strange thing is that if I use `font-family: Roboto Light, ...` then it works :( I do not understand the behavior here. How am I supposed to properly reference a font?

Comment: As always, it is pointless to downvote a question not explaining the reason why one did it... At least somebody understands what was wrong in the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I made a mistake in my first post, by putting 'font-family' twice. The second attribute should have been 'font-weight'. Sorry for that.

The other answer is correct. font-weight: and then 100-900 in increments of 100 will change the weight of the font (if the font has those weights available). Using Google fonts gives you a good idea of whats happening here. When you embed:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
```

you can see the different weights being provided from the Google Fonts content delivery network (CDN) which is a popular way to provide your website users with fonts they might otherwise not have installed on their system. So, if the above is in your HTML or you have Roboto installed, then:

```
.mytext {
    font-family: Roboto, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

will give you a regular weight Roboto, and:

```
.mytext-bold {
    font-family: Roboto, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

will give you bold. Hope this helps.

Comment: I believe that is because there is a font called Roboto Thin, probably installed on your system. I could be wrong though, I'm still unsure of your exact situation.

Comment: I made a mistake in my first post, by putting 'font-family' twice. The second attribute should have been 'font-weight'. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use a css property `font-weight`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight